# Find the continuity of a function without using L hopital

Tags: continuity

Let [x] denote the greatest integer function & f(x) be defined in a neighbourhood of 2 by

[image]

In this we have to find the values of A & f(2) in order that f(x) may be continuous at x = 2.

I thought to use L hopital to find LHL ,but could not use it because of greatest integer function.

Comment: Hint: in a left neighborhood of $2$ you can assume $[x+1]/4=1/2$.

Comment: @egreg then also there is indeterminancy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $1<x<2$ you have $[x+1]=2$, so the limit from the left is
$$
\lim_{x\to2^-}\frac{(\exp((x+2)\ln4))^{1/2}-16}{4^x-16}=
\lim_{x\to2^-}\frac{(\exp((x+2)\ln4))^{1/2}-16}{x-2}\frac{x-2}{4^x-16}
$$
Now,
$$
\lim_{x\to2^-}\frac{(\exp((x+2)\ln4))^{1/2}-16}{x-2}
$$
is the derivative at $2$ of the function
$$
g(x)=(\exp((x+2)\ln4))^{1/2}
$$
and
$$
g'(x)=\frac{\exp((x+2)\ln4)\ln4}{2(\exp((x+2)\ln4))^{1/2}}
$$
so
$$
g'(2)=\frac{4^4\ln4}{2(4^4)^{1/2}}=8\ln4
$$
Also
$$
\lim_{x\to2^-}\frac{4^x-16}{x-2}
$$
is the derivative at $2$ of the function $h(x)=4^x$ and $h'(x)=4^x\ln4$, so your limit is
$$
\frac{8\ln4}{16\ln4}=\frac{1}{2}
$$

For the limit from the right, do the substitution $t=x-2$, so you have
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}A\frac{1-\cos t}{t\tan t}=
\lim_{t\to0^+}A\frac{1-\cos t}{t^2}\frac{t}{\tan t}=\dotsb
$$